# How I can run selenium python with headless browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-headless

I have using python selenium to do some test but I don't want it to open any browser, so how I can use a headless browser?? can you guys help me :((
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/toanhac/Downloads/chromedriver')


url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox'
driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(15) 


driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(mail)
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `headless` to `True`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/toanhac/Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)


url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox'
driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(15) 


driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(mail)
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```